# Get the largest total starting of either by any two arrays(Maximum Sum Path in Two Arrays)

Tags: c

**Sample Input**

5

2 3 5 10 11

5

1 3 7 9 13

**Sample Output**

dollar 34

//Get total count sum starting from either array, If two arrays have same index it can **split** and continue getting total.. like 2+3+7+9+13=34 number 3 is same in 2nd index of each arrays so it change to other array and continue getting total.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){
    int a;
    scanf("%d",&a);
    int cash[a];
    for(int i=0;i<a;i++) 
        scanf("%d",&cash[i]);
    
    int b;
    scanf("%d",&b);
    int cash2[b];
    for(int i=0;i<b;i++) 
        scanf("%d",&cash2[i]);
    
    int total=0;
    for (int i=0;i<a;i++){
        total+=cash[i];
        if(cash[i]==cash2[i])
            total+=cash2[i];
    }
    printf("doller %d",total);
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I am not clear what you meant by `If two arrays have same index it can split.` Can you please explain it more ?

Comment: I meant If cash[i] =cash2[i]

Comment: Here for comparision you should use `==` in place of `=`, the value of `=` will be always true

Comment: thank you...output is like 2+3+7+9+13=34..

Comment: Did it solve your problem ?

Comment: still not. I want the output as dollar 34

Comment: I found one small issue, you haven't changed the array when you get a same number on both the arrays.

Comment: oops..How can I change that?... in line 19.. total+=cash2[i+1] ?

Comment: use printf("doller %d",total)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an int pointer to store the current array whose sum you will be calculating, once you get equal number in both the array, then you can swap the array to which pointer is pointing to. There was one more issue you forgot to use `%d` in `printf()`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){
    int a;
    scanf("%d",&a);
    int cash[a];
    for(int i=0;i<a;i++) 
        scanf("%d",&cash[i]);
    
    int b;
    scanf("%d",&b);
    int cash2[b];
    for(int i=0;i<b;i++) 
        scanf("%d",&cash2[i]);
    
    int total=0;
    int* currentArray = cash;
    for (int i=0;i<a;i++){
        total+=currentArray[i];
        if(cash[i]==cash2[i]){
            if(currentArray == cash){
                currentArray = cash2;
            }else{
                currentArray = cash;
            }
        }
    }
    printf("dollar %d",total);
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: (If program wants to find the largest sum) by this way

Comment: You can either start with the first array or with the second array, then your answer will be the maximum of the result you get from both of this.

Comment: Can you please add the link of the question

Comment: Hey @Yohombu, You might have to change the algorithm you are using. Whenever the value is same the cat can decide to switch the value or not.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219872/discussion-between-deepak-patankar-and-yohombu).

Answer (score 1):

use `printf("doller %d",total)`

In C programming language, %d is a format specifier.

Answer (score 1):

You can use two loops.

The first loop runs as long as you are summing up the first array. If both entries are equal, quit the loop.

The second loop continues by summing up the rest of the second array. You don't reset the index for this.

```c
    int total=0;
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < a; i++) {
        if (cash[i] == cash2[i]) { // could be in the loop's condition, but looks clearer here
            break;
        }
        total += cash[i];
    }
    for (/* no initial instruction*/; i < a; i++) {
        total += cash2[i];
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class MaximumSumPath
{
   
    int max(int x, int y)
    {
        return (x > y) ? x : y;
    }

   
    int maxPathSum(int ar1[], int ar2[], int m, int n)
    {
        
        int i = 0, j = 0;

         
        int result = 0, sum1 = 0, sum2 = 0;

        
        while (i < m && j < n)
        {
            
            if (ar1[i] < ar2[j])
                sum1 += ar1[i++];

                
            else if (ar1[i] > ar2[j])
                sum2 += ar2[j++];

                
            else
            {
                
                result += max(sum1, sum2);

                
                sum1 = 0;
                sum2 = 0;

                
                while (i < m && j < n && ar1[i] == ar2[j])
                {
                    result = result + ar1[i++];
                    j++;
                }
            }
        }

        
        while (i < m)
            sum1 += ar1[i++];

       
        while (j < n)
            sum2 += ar2[j++];

         
        result += max(sum1, sum2);

        return result;
    }

    
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        MaximumSumPath sumpath = new MaximumSumPath();

        

        int  sum = 0;
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        

        int m = s.nextInt();
        int ar1[] = new int[m];
        
        for(int i = 0; i < m; i++)
        {
            ar1[i] = s.nextInt();
        }

       

        int n = s.nextInt();
        int ar2[] = new int[n];
        
        for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            ar2[i] = s.nextInt();
        }
        System.out.println("dollar" + sumpath.maxPathSum(ar1, ar2, m, n));
    }
}
```